# Xcode 5 iPhone simulator is not having phone shape

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

The simulator is square without edges and home button.
why ? I am a new student .

[image]

Comment: Because your screen resolution is not big enough.

Comment: Set the simulator's scale to 100%.

Comment: The screen resolution is not big enough *or* simulator scale is not 100% (Cmd+1). Home button can be pressed using Cmd+H anytime.

Comment: Home is Shift + cmd + H

Comment: rotation is cmd+left/right arrow

Answer (score 4):

Is because resolution of your monitor screen

from apple docs:

*Even though iOS Simulator runs on all Macs, how it appears may differ between models. If you are using a computer whose screen is not large enough to display the entire simulator, only the screen of the simulated iOS device is shown, not the device border around it.*

see more : [Interacting with iOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator.html)

**Edit**
Even on large monitors the same effect will be achieved by setting scale less that 100% for simulator window.

Just for info: iPad(non-retina) simulator also show shape and home button on large monitor

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the screen size on your Mac. Small screens in which the whole simulator can't fit in, only the simulator-screen is shown :-)